# Two way binding to User Setting?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a boolean setting in my Properties/Settings.settings file, which basically stores per user "Right to Left" or "Left to Right" display mode.

I have a checkbox in my Ribbon which I have bound to the value. It appears however that the binding is only 1 way. Is there any way I can make this two way without having to write code to persist the setting?

**Clarification**

I have successfully configured the application to bind to the settings when it is first loaded. The problem is that this is a one-direction bind, i.e. the UI updates when settings are changed, but settings don't change when the UI is changed.

Hence my question...how can I configure two-way binding against user settings?

I can write event handlers to do all of this manually, but I figured that defies the point of using binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on my machine solely by using visual studio designer, so I would try ruling things out.

First, I would set the checkbox on a regular form and see if that helps. What component/library are you using for the ribbon?  Are you using DevExpress? I know DevExpress has no databinding support for Ribbon-controls. Are you using other components or your own code for that?

Second, note that the order of events is not as you might expect. It can very well be that first the CheckedChanged-event is fired and after that the value is synchronized with the Settings. So instead of using the CheckedChanged event I would use a separate button that gets the focus and check within that handler if the value is synchronized.

Third, you could also override the CheckedChanged event and push the new databinding value to the underlying datasource. I've done that for many controls and works like a charm.

Comment: I went with the CheckedChanged option. Thanks.

Comment: You say this works on your machine? I tested this out on my Ultimate Version and cannot get this to work without the changes I listed in my answer. As far as I can read from documentation and other questions, this is the only way. So, I am curious how you are doing this that it is working right out of the box?

Comment: I'm not working "out of the box", the CheckedChange event handler I have written essentially just calls the save method anyway. I gave up on the original problem on the basis it was taking me more time to research than just coding a workaround.

Thankyou both for your help though.

Comment: @Justin Create a Winform-project, add a Setting with name cb, Type bool, Value False. In Form1 add a checkbox and a button. Through the Properties set checkbox1.ApplicationSettings.Checked to cb. In the click-eventhandler of the button add MessageBox.Show(Properties.Settings.Default.cb.ToString()); Run the application, check the checkbox and click the button. Settings are synchronized: works out of the box.

Answer (score 4):

OK, after some digging it appears that you will need to somewhat implement this, however it might not be as clean as you want it to be. Basically, your binding object must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (this is the part that kept giving me trouble...I was thinking the CheckBox must implement this interface, but it is the object that the checkbox is bound to), which `Properties.Settings.Default` does. So, all you need to do is the following

Hook into the OnPropertyChanged event of Property.Settings.Default:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.PropertyChanged +=
    new PropertyChangedEventHandler(Default_PropertyChanged);
```

Then, when any bound property changes, just call the Save method:

```
void Default_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Basically, when you bind the object, it does change the `Settings.Default.[Setting]` appropriately. It just does not call `Save` on each of those changes. You must implement that part of things.

Comment: I am already calling .Save(), but the problem seems to be that the Properties object is not being updated when I change the status of the bound control.

Comment: I guess that is the case...nevermind, just means cluttering up my codebehind with extra event handlers. I've clarified my original question incase somebody else comes along with any ideas! Thanks anyway.

Comment: @AdamKing Actually, take a look at this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yyxh69h.aspx  It seems to be what you are looking for? I will update as my answer if this works I am verifying...otherwise this article seems to sum up your options otherwise: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/255512/binding-an-application-setting-to-a-control-property

Comment: That is what I already have in place, but it only appears to be working one way...

Comment: @AdamKing OK, I updated my answer with what looks like the best solution. You need to manually call Save. All the binding is doing is setting the value without truly persisting it. This seems like it might be cleaner than using the CheckChanged option as you do not need to care about which specific setting is changing.